# lost focus event in c# user control with dynamic text boxes (winforms)

Tags: c#

I have a user control in c# where I am dynamically adding textboxes based on run-time user selections.  I need to raise a lost focus (or leave?) event for these text boxes.  Any suggestions?

Comment: where is your code for dynamically creating these textboxes?

Comment: Which framework are you working on?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a textbox, add this line :

```
mytextBox.LostFocus += TextBox_LostFocus;
```

note that when you write += intellisense automatically suggest to press tab to automatic creation of the handler function. If you press tab twice you will get

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

delete throw exception line and replace it with your stuff.